# Is it possible to add multiple, column-aligned controls as ListViewItems within XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` in which I need to add a fixed amount of items to in the XAML.  (I don't need to dynamically add items to the list and I want to handle data binding from within the xaml as well.)

I understand how to add text as `ListViewItems` simply with `<ListViewItem content="blah"/>`

What I want to do is something like:

```
<ListViewItem><TextBox/><Label/></ListViewItem>
```

*where the TextBox is appointed to the first column in my listview and the label to the second.*

Is this at all possible to do within the XAML only?  No code-behind.  Would it be doable with a datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one row in your ListView, with multiple columns, you can change the ItemsPanel to a StackPanel with horizontal Orientation

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

If you need more than one row in your ListView, you can still place more than one element (horizontally) in a row by using a stackpanel as your ListViewItem, and placing children controls in it.

```
<ListView>
  <ListViewItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox></TextBox>
      <Label></Label>
    </StackPanel>
  </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Edit:

To have a column with a certain type of control, you can assign a CellTemplate to a GridView's Column.

```
<ListView>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="TextBoxColumn">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Anything}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

However, you would still need to populate the gridview from codebehind.

Comment: Do you need them to appear as columns next to each other in the same row? or do you need the items in separate row/columns?

Comment: next to each other in the same row.  Aligned to the gridview columns

Comment: I'll edit the answer, You could place a stackpanel with horizontal orientation as your ListViewItem if you need multiple rows, and if you need only one row, you can change the itemspanel orientation to horizontal.

Comment: I may just do that.  The real issue though is that the controls need to align with the gridview columns.  There are two columns in my listview and the user can resize them.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention in the question that you had a GridView Initially, so the question wasn't very specific. I don't think there's a way to add rows in XAML only, you could make a Celltemplate for the columns.